# Python not standart list sorting

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list like this: `[2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]` and I want to sort it to get   `[1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2]`. How I can do it in good pythonic way? I've tried like this:

```
import random
alist = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
random.shuffle(alist)

print(alist)

ones = []
twos = []
threes = []

for item in alist:
    if item == 1:
        ones.append(item)
    elif item == 2:
        twos.append(item)
    else:
        threes.append(item)

ordered_list = []
ordered_list.extend(ones)
ordered_list.extend(threes)
ordered_list.extend(twos)

print(ordered_list)
```

But I guess it's not the best way to do it. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: what is the logic behind that sortening?

Comment: Is this the only use you will have? i.e. there will never be a (let say) 4 to be sorted and you always have 2 elements per digit?

Comment: By what criteria do you want to sort to produce that output?

Comment: If it only contains `1`, `2` and `3`, this can be done in linear time with a variant of "radix sort".

Comment: I am not sure if this can be called as sorting :-)

Comment: Idea is i want to have order that I've mentioned in post. alist can have more elements per digit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a dict that holds the order of your items, and then provide a lookup into it as the key argument to the regular `sort()` method.

```
orderlist = [1, 3, 2]
order = {item: prio for prio, item in enumerate(orderlist)}
# order = {1:0, 3:1, 2:2}
alist = [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1]
alist.sort(key=lambda i: order[i])
alist
```

outputs

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2]
```